# How to add and compile with ARM in QT5.6.0?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, gcc, ubuntu-14.04

My System Configuration is:Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS/64 bit and I installed qt version "qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.6.0.run".

I want to create GUI application(Dialog based) with ARM compiler.
when i am try to set compiler it gives me error like
"The compiler (arm-linux-generic-elf-32 bit) cannot produce code for the QT version QT 5.6.0 GCC 64bit (x86-linux-generic-elf-64bit)"

and not able to compile with arm.

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: You need Qt compiled for ARM as well. Can't you compile the code directly on the ARM machine ?

Comment: Yes,i am able to build with gcc as default compiler in qt.but now able to build as arm also i can't compile code in arm device as right now can't get arm device.

Comment: You must cross-compile, this way you can compile for arm on your pc